# Issue adding library :cannot find the class

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to use code from sample pie chart code of achartengine. On adding the code and library, application crashes. I added this library:`achartengine-1.0.0.jar` using Buildpath-->configure build path-->libraries-->add external jar.

But this library is show in referenced libraries instead of showing in private library of eclipse. 
I used this code from sample:

```
code = new String[] {
                                            "Eclair & Older", "Froyo", "Gingerbread", "Honeycomb",
                                            "IceCream Sandwich", "Jelly Bean" 
                                    };      

                                    // Pie Chart Slice Values
                                    double[] distribution = { 3.9, 12.9, 55.8, 1.9, 23.7, 1.8 } ;

                                    // Color of each Pie Chart Slices
                                    int[] colors = { Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN, Color.RED,
                                                     Color.YELLOW };

                                    // Instantiating CategorySeries to plot Pie Chart       
                                    CategorySeries distributionSeries = new CategorySeries(" Android version distribution as on October 1, 2012");
                                    for(int i=0 ;i < distribution.length;i++){
                                        // Adding a slice with its values and name to the Pie Chart
                                        distributionSeries.add(code[i], distribution[i]);
                                    }   

                                    // Instantiating a renderer for the Pie Chart
                                    DefaultRenderer defaultRenderer  = new DefaultRenderer();       
                                    for(int i = 0 ;i<distribution.length;i++){ 

                                        // Instantiating a render for the slice
                                        SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();       
                                        seriesRenderer.setColor(colors[i]);
                                        seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

                                        // Adding the renderer of a slice to the renderer of the pie chart
                                        defaultRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);
                                    }

                                    defaultRenderer.setChartTitle("Android version distribution as on October 1, 2012 ");
                                    defaultRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
                                    defaultRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);                    

                                    // Getting a reference to view group linear layout chart_container



                                    // Getting PieChartView to add to the custom layout
                                    mChart = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(getBaseContext(), distributionSeries, defaultRenderer);



                                    // Adding the pie chart to the custom layout
                                    contentView.addView(mChart);
```

and application crashes and shows this error:

```
   12-09 11:23:14.356: E/dalvikvm(354): Could not find class 'org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries', referenced from method com.example.aimpaas.MainActivity$2$1.onClick
12-09 11:23:14.356: W/dalvikvm(354): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 824 (Lorg/achartengine/model/CategorySeries;) in Lcom/example/aimpaas/MainActivity$2$1;
12-09 11:23:14.356: D/dalvikvm(354): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x00e7
12-09 11:23:14.356: D/dalvikvm(354): VFY: dead code 0x00e9-0136 in Lcom/example/aimpaas/MainActivity$2$1;.onClick (Landroid/view/View;)V
12-09 11:23:14.356: D/dalvikvm(354): VFY: dead code 0x01a0-01cd in Lcom/example/aimpaas/MainActivity$2$1;.onClick (Landroid/view/View;)V
12-09 11:23:15.726: D/AndroidRuntime(354): Shutting down VM
12-09 11:23:15.726: W/dalvikvm(354): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-09 11:23:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(354): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 11:23:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(354): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries
12-09 11:23:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at com.example.aimpaas.MainActivity$2$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:229)
12-09 11:23:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-09 11:23:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-09 11:23:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-09 11:23:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-09 11:23:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-09 11:23:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-09 11:23:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 11:23:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-09 11:23:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-09 11:23:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-09 11:23:15.726: E/AndroidRuntime(354):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 11:23:17.797: I/Process(354): Sending signal. PID: 354 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed android dependencies from java build path then clean and rebuild a project (this work for me).